# Hyperlink to Report in SSRS2013

Tags: reporting-services

I have a stored procedure returning data and one of the items is for a link to a report that I want to apply to a textbox action so someone can click on it and open a report.

This is an example of what is being returned by the SP:

http:///ReportServer_SFIFVSQLIP1/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSummary%2fLineTimeAccounting&rs:Command=Render

But when I click on the hyperlink it is taking me to this URL which doesn't exist:
http://reportserver/?%2FSummary%2FLineTimeAccounting%22

Any thoughts?

Comment: My guess is the issue is with the colons and underscores being passed back from the SP. I modified the report to use the URL and when I click on the link it opens just fine, so definitely something happening between the report and stored procedure.

Comment: Can you post the code that is generating the URL?

Comment: Well, I am just using the built in stuff in Visual Studio. I setup an action to go to URL on click and the select URL is a field being returned by the stored procedure.. So the uRL is =Fields!ReportLink.Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It wasn't the underscore but the Unicode characters for the black slash (%2f).

I changed

> http:///ReportServer_SFIFVSQLIP1/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSummary%2fLineTimeAccounting&rs:Command=Render

To

> http:///ReportServer_SFIFVSQLIP1/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Summary/LineTimeAccounting&rs:Command=Render

In the SQL table and it works fine now.